# Swift: converting between Arrays of 'Protocol' and Arrays of implementing Class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics

Consider a protocol and a class that implements it:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var x: Int { get }
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {
    var x: Int = 5
}
```

I have an array of type `[MyClass]` and I wish to assign it to a variable of type `[MyProtocol]`. However, this causes a error when attempted in Playground (XCode 6.3, Swift 1.2):

```
var classArr: [MyClass] = [MyClass(), MyClass()]

var protocolArrA: [MyProtocol] = classArr // Causes error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
var protocolArrB: [MyProtocol] = classArr as [MyProtocol] // Causes error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
var protocolArrC: [MyProtocol] = [MyProtocol](classArr) // Causes error: Cannot find an initializer for type [MyProtocol[ that accepts an argument list of type [MyClass]
```

**What is the correct way to make this assignment in Swift?**

P.S. Interestingly, when using a base class instead of a protocol, the expressions for `protocolArrA` and `protocolArrB` work without error.

It is also interesting to note that assigning a newly created instance of [MyClass] also works well:

```
var protocolArrD: [MyProtocol] = [MyClass]()   // A-OK!
```

Comment: Managed to reproduce your problem. It seems a lot like a bug :-/ The manual cast via `classArr.map{$0 as MyProtocol}` could be a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use map to cast each element to the desired type:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var x: Int { get }
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {
    var x: Int = 5
}

var classArr: [MyClass] = [MyClass(), MyClass()]

var protocolArrA:[MyProtocol] = classArr.map{$0 as MyProtocol}
var andBack:[MyClass] = protocolArrA.map{$0 as! MyClass}
```

---

Note, Swift is able to infer all of the array types above, so this can be written more succinctly as:

```
var classArr = [MyClass(), MyClass()]

var protocolArrA = classArr.map{$0 as MyProtocol}
var andBack = protocolArrA.map{$0 as! MyClass}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    var x: Int { get }
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {
    @objc var x: Int = 5
}
```

Both works if using @objc

```
 var classArr: [MyClass] = [MyClass(), MyClass()]     
 var protocolArrA: [MyProtocol] = classArr
 var protocolArrB: [MyProtocol] = classArr as [MyProtocol]
```

Comment: classArr is of type `[MyClass]` on purpose. I don't want to re-define it as `[MyProtocol]`. The actual code is much more complex, and I distilled only the portions causing the problem (which is not context-dependant IMHO).